# Can light concentrated through convex lens be "cooled down?"

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, visible-light, applied-physics, design

I've just been assigned this biology design project where I'm being tasked to create a device for maximizing "sunlight exposure" of crops and am unsure of this particular question, for the design of course.

Asides from this, could anyone briefly explain the significance of light in photosynthesis, and how filtering light could POTENTIALLY, increase the rate of this (does it?)

In retrospect I believe I require sufficient knowledge on optics to properly design this device, of which I am admittedly not an expert of; to be fair I more or less have no clue as to its more... practical concepts. Mind if anyone PREFERABLY point me towards any theories of interest or relevance to my task?

Thanks.

Comment: Filtering frequencies out of a beam of light will reduce the energy delivered to the leaf (and that's about where the physics stops), but I vaguely remember hearing about how plants didn't like being exposed to certain frequencies, and so could have their efficiency reduced by exposure to them. You might have better luck asking a biologist, there might be a frequency range that plant chemistry does not like for some reason.

Comment: So-called _[Low-E Glass](http://glassed.vitroglazings.com/glasstopics/how_lowe_works.aspx)_ is widely used in architecture to reflect away the Sun's infrared light while transmitting its visible light. That might be a help. I think something like half of the power of sunlight is in infrared wavelengths that play no role in photosynthesis.

Comment: It might also be worth looking at the lighting that indoor hydroponics systems use, since presumably these are designed to maximise growth and (hopefully) have taken into consideration the optimal intensity and wavelength(s).

Comment: Further to my previous comment, try [this SE Gardening answer](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/22021)...